# Suddenly can't find several apps in Market

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, google-play-store, motorola-milestone

So I've been using several apps for a while now, and all of the sudden, I can't seem to find them in the Market anymore. If I look on the "My downloads" page in the Market, it does show as installed, and I can even update them if I hit "Update all". However I can't seem to navigate to the apps's page, neither through the "My downloads" page nor through simply searching for it. It just says it can't find the item. Note that this doesn't occur with all apps, just specific ones.

As mentioned before, the apps were installed earlier and I didn't have this problem back then.

The apps I've run across that have this problem so far are the following

- WhatsApp
- eBuddy
- PingChat!
- ebuddy XMS

I've tried uninstalling them through app management, but this leaves me with an uninstalled app with no possibility of re-installing it through the Market. I'm using a UK Motorola Milestone running the official Froyo update. Any ideas anyone? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the content rating filter on my phone was the culprit! I recently updated my phone to Froyo and the Market's content rating filter was added after the update! Just set it to "All Applications" in the Market's settings screen.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of that :P

Comment: @MatthewRead You did point me in the right direction I looked on market.google.com and found an article on it in the knowledge base! :D

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the app listings were changed so that they don't show up for users with certain phones, OS versions, or carriers.  The best way to tell for sure might be to try installing one of the apps from the Market website, [like eBuddy](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ebuddy.android), and seeing if it gives you an error (and what the error says).

Comment: Nope, it doesnt give me an error, it says it will be installed on my device shortly, but it never does.

Comment: That's quite bizarre.  Maybe you should try clearing the Market data (`Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All`, find the Market, click it, click Clear Data).

Comment: Found out! Check my answer! Thanks for your help anyway! :D